# How can I show server up time in Grafana?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, monitoring, grafana, prometheus-node-exporter

I want to show the percentage of the server (or service) uptime in Grafana for the last month.
The monitoring service collects data with Prometheus node exporter.

```
uptime % = ( up / down ) * 100
```

Comment: What is the Node Exporter metric to see the uptime? I think you must use, for example, the Blackbox Exporter (https://github.com/prometheus/blackbox_exporter) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [MarceloÁviladeOliveira](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4653675/marcelo-%C3%81vila-de-oliveira) said I used Black-Box Exporter with this PromQL :

```
avg_over_time(probe_success{job="$job",instance=~"$instance"}[30d]) * 100
```